# Best Practices in extending on a premium Shopify theme

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

i am kind of going into migrating a couple of Woo websites to Shopify. And we are not talking about some drop shipping websites here, think more along the lines of brick and mortar premium stores with 500-2k products and variations.

So, most of the heavylifting will be done via Shopify premium themes. But i was wondering if need arises to have some custom CSS or JS, or custom page templates, how would one go about extending the theme?

1. Is there a hooks system, or crappy template overriding (like WP) or anything similar?
2. And if there is, how can i be sure that using it won't break the auto-theme-updates we get from shopify?
3. Once those two questions are dealt with, another one arises - what tooling would you suggest as a build system? Webpack with babel i guess, but are there any boilerplate projects around?

Some guidelines:

- No, i do not want to edit the theme as that would break the auto-update.
- No, i do not want to clone the theme and edit the new one, as that would break the auto-update.
- No, i do not want to use React or Vue, as that is just silly.

**Thank you :)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for child themes in Shopify like WP - there is no such thing there.

The only way to modify a theme without touching any of the code is to create s custom APP and use the [ScriptTag API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/online-store/scripttag) where you will include a custom JS file that will add some JS logic or CSS for the theme.

If you plan to make liquid changes, you must modify the theme, there is no way around that.

Any other approach will require modifying the files.

Please have in mind that Shopify themes doesn't receive updates too often, since they don't have the option to modify the back-end, security is low risk for them and they don't rely on APPs to function properly, in contrast to WordPress sites where there are constant updates that fix core security issues and plugin issues.

BUT you are complicating your job too much, just modify the theme or at least create a custom separate CSS and JS files for your logic.

Have in mind that if you install ANY APP that modifies the front-end of the Shopify ( which most of them do ) your auto-update theme will break the Apps and it will no longer work. So I actually recommend not relying on auto updates at all, since this will be a huge issue!

For the last question look into https://shopify.github.io/themekit/

In addition please consider splitting your questions in different topics from now on if you have multiply ones.